# Print all states of getting from a random 256 bit private key to a corresponding encoded BTC address

Tags: address-generation

I wonder if it is possible to print what's going on under the hood regarding the process of getting from a random binary number to a BTC address.

It will look something like this:

Input: `a random 256 binary number`

Output: `print()`

Printing all possible sequential states from that number to a BTC address.

**PRIVATE KEY STATES**

```
binary privKey [k] -> decimal privKey -> hexadecimal privKey -> WIF privKey
```

**PUBLIC KEY STATES**

```
decimal pubKey print(x,y) -> print K where [K=(x,y)] -> hexadecimal PubKey (A) -> print A=RIPEMD160(SHA2569(K))
```

It will help a lot of people interested in the details of creating BTC addresses, from the elliptic curve private to public key process (K=k*G) to the other encoding steps until the final address.

On GitHub and other places, `.js` or `.py` libraries just print the WIF key and the address, and sometimes the hexadecimal public key as well.

Thanks.

Comment: If you really want this, I think your best bet is to take some existing code and add print statements wherever you like, or single-step it with a debugger.  I doubt you'll find code where this has already been done, mainly because I don't think it will actually be as informative as you guess.  The individual arithmetical computations aren't very informative one by one; it's better to understand the mathematical constructions that they express collectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my code [`bitcoin-in-tiny-pieces`](https://github.com/circulosmeos/bitcoin-in-tiny-pieces) can serve to follow all the steps: each script is devoted to just a step of the process and has the minimal code to fulfil it.

Python is easy to follow if you're not a programmer, and there are comments that point to the documentation sources, though for example going from private to public key is all maths.

Each script is self-explanatory:

- bitcoin-public-from-private.py
- bitcoin-wif-from-private-key.py
- bitcoin-address-from-public-key.py
- bitcoin-get-address-balance.py

Answer (score 1):

The [bitcoin developper](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#wallet-files) pages show the steps in all details for type 1 addresses.

For the type 1 addresses, there is a good [link here](http://gobittest.appspot.com/Address) to test results.

Then there is HD wallets, [Segwit](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/), and many other extensions...

Maybe it is good to start for type 1 addresses, and extend with your ideas of "under the hood crypto". I stick to Nate's comment though.